# AppFabric Topic Subscription

Tags: appfabric, azure-appfabric

I am trying to assemble a simple AppFabric Topic whereby messages are sent and received using the SessionId. The code does not abort, but brokeredMessage is always null. Here is the code:

```
// BTW, the topic already exists

var messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.Create(uri, credentials);
var topicClient = messagingFactory.CreateTopicClient(topicName);
var sender = topicClient.CreateSender();
var message = BrokeredMessage.CreateMessage("Top of the day!");
message.SessionId = "1";
sender.Send(message);

var subscription = topic.AddSubscription("1", new SubscriptionDescription { RequiresSession = true});
var mikeSubscriptionClient =  messagingFactory.CreateSubscriptionClient(subscription);
var receiver = mikeSubscriptionClient.AcceptSessionReceiver("1");
BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage;
receiver.TryReceive(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), out brokeredMessage); // brokeredMessage always null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems in your code:

1. You create a subscription **AFTER** you send the message. You need to create a subscription before sending, because a subscription tells the topic to, in a sense, copy, the message to several different "buckets".
2. You are using TryReceive but are not checking for its result. It returns true, if a message was received, and false if not (e.g. Timeout has occured).

I am writing my sample application and will post it on our blog today. I will post the link here as well. But until then, move the subscription logic to before sending the message, and the receiver after it and you will start seeing results.

**Update:**
As promised, here is the link to my blog post on [getting started with AppFabric Queues, Topics, Subscriptions.](http://lab.studiopesec.com/windows-azure-appfabric-queue-quick-start/)